# Блокировать кнопку Submit при повторном нажатии до обновления страницы

Tags: php, html, submit

Есть кнопка

```
<form method="POST" action="...">
...
<button type="submit">click me</button>
</form>
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопка становилась неактивной до обновления страницы (по нажатию идет отправка данных и страница обновляется).

Модифицирую до вида `<button type="submit" onclick="this.disabled = true; this.innerHTML='in progress'">click me</button>`

В результате после нажатия кнопка блокируется, но данные почему-то не отправляются (и, соотв, страница не обновляется). В чём косяк?

UPD.
Вариант

```
<script>
$('#multi_mod').one('submit', function() {
    $(this).find('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
</script>

<form name="multi_mod" method="POST" action="...">
...
<input type="submit" value="click me">
</form>
```

у меня вообще не работает(т.е. данные отправляются, но кнопка не блокируется!).
Где косяк? Какие ещё могут быть варианты ???

Comment: PD https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323948/disabling-the-button-after-once-click

Comment: Вариант 
<script>
$('#multi_mod').one('submit', function() {
    $(this).find('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
</script>

<form name="multi_mod" method="POST" action="...">
...
<input type="submit" value="click me">
</form>

у меня вообще не работает(т.е. данные отправляются, но кнопка не блокируется!).

Comment: для варианта из UPD Подключили jquery?

Comment: да, https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js

Comment: Вроде не сложный вопрос, чувствую что я где-то тупанул, но где ??))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Явно указал `this` и всё заработало

```
$('#multi_mod').one('submit', function() {
    $('#btn_mod').find('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
});


<form id="multi_mod" name="multi_mod" method="POST" action="...">
...
<input type="submit" value="click me" id="btn_mod">
</form>
```

Вот такое вот неожиданное решение!))
Может кому-то поможет.

Answer (score 1):

Выше 1.6 jQuery попробуйте использовать .prop:

```
$( 'input[type="submit"]').prop( "disabled", true );//0    
$( 'input[type="submit"]' ).prop( "disabled", false );//1
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно при клике клике на кнопку заблокировать ее ***=>*** event должен сработать после отправки формы. Попробуйте использовать функцию `.submit()` для обработки события формы:

```js
$('form').submit(function(e){
    let input = $(this).find('input');
    input.attr('disabled', true);
});
```

Event `submit` срабатывает на форму, когда вы ее отправляете. Дальше вы ищите `input` в форме и присваиваете ему атрибут `disabled`.

Comment: Да, это как раз вариант из базового примера. 
`
$('#myForm').one('submit', function() {
    $(this).find('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
});`

Comment: Немного измененный :)

Comment: ну `.one()` - это другой метод, для в вашем случае лучше использовать `.submit()`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Я уже отмучал этот вопрос с помощью `.one()`, но допускаю, что `.submit()` тоже норм вариант, просто сейчас нет времени/возможности проверить.